# How do I switch between more than 2 weapons?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-3

In my loadout right now, I've got an assault rifle, a shotgun, and a heavy pistol.  (I've double checked that I'm supposed to be carrying 3, so it's not just an inventory brain-fart issue)  According to the hint tips I've seen, I can hold X to switch between my weapons.

However, Shepard just keeps reaching for either the pistol or the assault rifle!  How do I get him to pull out the shotgun?  I've tried holding the button longer or just tapping it, but tapping just reloads, and regardless of how long I hold, he still switches between the pistol and the AR.

Comment: I've got Kinect support, so I guess I could shout **SHOTGUN** every time I wanted to switch, but that seems like it's likely to give my wife, the kids, or my friends on Xbox Live heart attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To swap to a third weapon, you'll have to navigate into your powers(or guns depending on platform) screen to select the weapon manually:

- **PC** - Shift
- **Xbox** - LB (Thanks @hammar)
- **PS3** - L2

The quick swap button you are using only swaps the current weapon with the most recently used weapon.

Comment: On the XBox, the powers and weapons screens are separate and accessed by holding RB or LB, respectively.

Comment: It's the Guns screen, not the power screen, on consoles anyway. IT's LB on Xbox and L2 on PS3.