# How does one pick the two weapons one wants to fast "X" switch between?

Tags: mass-effect-3

First, please confirm my understanding:

- you can carry up to 5 weapons
- you can fast switch using "X" between two at a time

I am having trouble setting the two fast switch weapons. For instance, say I currently have my sniper and shotgun selected as my fast switch weapons. I then get in close quarters and want to swap my sniper fast switch weapon to an assault rifle. To do that I fast switch "X" to the sniper, bring up the weapon wheel, select the assault rifle. Then when I press "X" it switches back to the sniper rifle. This is so maddening. How does one pick the two weapons one wants to fast "X" switch between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>X</kbd> is not fast switch - it is "switch to previous weapon".

If you want to switch between Assault Rifles and Shotguns (or whatever), you just need to make sure that those are the last two weapon types you've actually used.

Comment: "used" as in selected or selected and actually fired?

Comment: Hi, @Mark, welcome to gaming! If this answered your question, make sure to click the check mark under the number to the right of this answer!

Comment: @mark it's selected, not fired.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and for your fast answer. I think my edits to your reply hid my followup question.  
Did you mean "used" as in selected, or selected and actually fired?

Comment: Oops and now I see your answer, never mind the time warp happening over here. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

The two weapons you switch between with X are always the *last two* weapons you selected from the weapon wheel.  There's no way to override this as far as I know.

I learned more about weapon switching when I asked this question, which may be relevant to your interests:

[How do I switch between more than 2 weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54198/how-do-i-switch-between-more-than-2-weapons)